# How to fix Buffer.from is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, buffer

I'm getting a in my React Native project: TypeError _$$_REQUIRE(...).Buffer.from(...) is not a function, and I can't figure out the reason for the error.

Below, I'm sharing the code where I encountered the error.

```
/* import
 const Buffer = require('buffer').Buffer
*/



sendFiles(id, files, type = 'single', body = '', directSend = true) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let count = 0
  files.map(file => {
    let receiveId = id
    let isGroup = type !== 'single'

    let onLoadFile = data => {
      if (data.indexOf(',') !== -1) data = data.split(',')[1]
      let dataBase64 = data
      let bufferData

      try {
        bufferData = Buffer.from(data, 'base64') <= the line where i got the error

        (data = {
          uri: file.uri,
          type: file.type,
          name: file.name,
        })
      } catch (err) {
        onErrorAlert('file:not:processed')
        return
      }
      ...
```

Versions I'm using:

```
 buffer: 6.0.3
 react: ^18.2.0
 react-native: ^0.70.5
 node: v16.17.0
```

I'm waiting for your comments on how I can solve the error.